# Creating layers of 'divs' and displaying them on clicking corresponding buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a webpage in which I have a stack of divs, and corresponding buttons for them. 
On clicking the buttons, I need to be able to display the div.

The problem I am facing is that the moment I click the any button, the div is displayed, but subsequent button clicks do not display their corresponding divs.

I used set `display: none` for all the divs, and on clicking the corresponding div, the display is set to `display: block` using `div.style.display = "block"`.

Following is the complete javascript:

```
function init() {
      var i = 0;

      var add = document.getElementById("add-button");
      add.addEventListener("click", addNote);

      function addNote() {
        var mainClass = "wholenote" + i;
        var note_name = prompt("Enter a name for the note");
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        var node = document.createTextNode(note_name);
        div.appendChild(node);
        div.className = "note";
        div.className += " " + mainClass;

        var inputButton = document.createElement("input");
        inputButton_id = "deletetheNote" + i;
        inputButton.setAttribute("id", inputButton_id);
        inputButton.setAttribute("type", "image");
        inputButton.setAttribute("src", "Dustbin.png");
        inputButton.className += "deleteButton";
        div.appendChild(inputButton);

        var element = document.getElementById("side-bar");
        element.appendChild(div);

        noteArea = document.createElement("div");
        noteArea.className = "note-area";
        noteArea.className += " " + mainClass;
        var noteName = "note" + i;
        noteArea.setAttribute("id", noteName);
        document.getElementById("main-area").appendChild(noteArea);


        div.addEventListener("click", function() {
          document.getElementById(noteName).style.display = "block";
        }, true);

        inputButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
          var elems = document.getElementsByClassName(mainClass);
          console.log(elems);
          for (var k = elems.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            var parent = elems[k].parentNode;
            parent.removeChild(elems[k]);
          }
        });
        i++;
      }
    }
```

Following is the code that sets the display to none/block:

```
div.addEventListener("click", function() {
          document.getElementById(noteName).style.display = "block";
        }, true);
```

The 'divs' and the buttons are both being created dynamically, and 'noteName' is the variable that stores the 'id' for each div and naming it in every iteration of the function `addNote()`.

PS I'm actually using the 'div' element as a button, and hence referring to them as 'buttons' above.

Any help?

Comment: can you paste your code in the question. The problem is not obvious

Comment: Post your code, that set display none/block when you click the buttons

Comment: I added the code. Let me know if there is any other information you need (I am a new learner). I need a way to hide all other divs and display only the one the button was clicked for.

Comment: You want to show the divs when you click on a button right? So, why is the event listener added to the div and not the button?

Comment: I'm actually using the 'div' element for buttons. Forgot to mention that.

Comment: I added the whole javascript above. I know it is difficult to understand the problem, but I don't really know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your document should not have duplicating ID's on the same page as this does not follow the W3 specification. `getElementById()` returns the first element within the collection (thats why only one div shows but not the rest). Use a class selector instead.

Example (uses jQuery but the principal is the same): https://jsfiddle.net/hq7c7h2u/